# Unable to install Python build with shared library using pyenv on MacOS 11.1

Tags: python, macos, macos-big-sur, pyenv, apple-m1

I am running into an error when using trying to install Python 3.8.6 with a shared library enabled. I am using PyEnv 1.2.23 on an M1 Macbook Pro.

In particular, running:

```
$ env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.8.6
```

returns the error message:

```
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.6.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.6/Python-3.8.6.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.6...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk
BUILD FAILED (OS X 11.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/b7/nnczj7h90wn8ds7ht2ljn2l80000gn/T/python-build.20210309124942.97911
Results logged to /var/folders/b7/nnczj7h90wn8ds7ht2ljn2l80000gn/T/python-build.20210309124942.97911.log

Last 10 log lines:
checking size of _Bool... 1
checking size of off_t... 8
checking whether to enable large file support... no
checking size of time_t... 8
checking for pthread_t... yes
checking size of pthread_t... 8
checking size of pthread_key_t... 8
checking whether pthread_key_t is compatible with int... no
configure: error: Unexpected output of 'arch' on OSX
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.
```

I've also tried:

```
$ arch -x86_64 env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared" pyenv install 3.8.6
```

and I get the same output.

I have also tried this:

```
$ brew install zlib
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib"
$ export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include
```

and alas, no avail.

any ideas? thanks~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

M1 support wasn't added to Python until 3.9.1.  You'll need to upgrade.